# difficulty in installing ruby-bundler and update headers in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, shell, ubuntu, installation, terminal

I'm learning ruby on rails and therefore require installation of some gems for app.
I'm trying to install ruby-bundler but getting errors.
need some help..
i'll paste the commands i tried in my terminal.
thanks in advance.

```
hp@ubuntu:~$ bundle install --without production
The program 'bundle' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler

hp@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler
[sudo] password for hp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ruby ruby1.8
Suggested packages:
ri ruby-dev ruby1.8-examples ri1.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ruby ruby-bundler ruby1.8
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Need to get 143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,139 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main ruby all 4.8
Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe ruby-bundler all 1.0.15-     0ubuntu2
Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main ruby1.8 i386 1.8.7.352- 2ubuntu0.1
Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Failed to fetch             http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby1.8/ruby1.8_1.8.7.352-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby-     defaults/ruby_4.8_all.deb  Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/ruby-bundler/ruby-bundler_1.0.15-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
hp@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease                             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner i386 Packages                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner TranslationIndex              
Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com oneiric InRelease                                                           

Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com oneiric-updates InRelease                   

Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com oneiric-security InRelease

Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com oneiric Release.gpg
Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg
Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Err http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com oneiric-security Release.gpg
Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg      Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

what could be the reasons??
is it related to ubuntu archive mirror?
i am not even able to upgrade due to broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a problem with network

Comment: no..i think the server was overloaded.so i changed the software sources.it's working but showing 'you have held broken packages' on any updation.

Answer (score 0):

You do not include much about what you have already done to get Ruby installed correctly so I would refer to this Blog Post on [Installing Ruby on Ubuntu](http://ascarter.net/2011/01/02/rails-development-on-ubuntu-10.10.html)

One thing to note when using Ubuntu as a Development platform it is wise to install a few dev tools and libraries that are covered in this Blog post.

1/31/13 - If you have unmet Package dependencies and your installing from 3rd party sources and getting the Package dependency error. Go into your Software Sources and make sure that Restricted and Universe are unchecked.

One possible cause of unmet dependencies could be corrupted package database, and/or some packages that did not install properly.

To try and fix this problem open Terminal and run the following command

```
xyz@ubuntuhost$ sudo apt-get clean
```

apt-get clean Clears the Local repo of all files / Packages and leaves only the Lock File.

IF that does not fix your issue then try these three commands in the order below.

```
xyz@ubuntuhost$ sudo apt-get -f install

xyz@ubuntuhost$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

xyz@ubuntuhost$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Post the output of that last command. If it found and fixed something it will report something like

```
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

or

```
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

The -f stands for “fix broken”. Apt will attempt to correct broken dependencies. If you manually installed a package that had unmet dependencies, apt-get will install those dependencies, if possible, otherwise it may simply remove the package that you installed in order to resolve the problem.

Give this a shot.

Comment: i tried to update by commands in blog,but terminal always comes out with 'unable to corrct problems,you have held broken packages'.

Comment: You might try running Update Manager and let it update / fix the broken packages. What are the packages it is complaining about?

Comment: '    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3) but 2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
       Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3) but 2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3.1 is to be installed'

Comment: Have you run Update Manager to try to fix these?

Comment: whenever i try to do so,it says wait for apt-get to exit.so, i am upgrading from terminal.should i need to upgrade to latest version of ubuntu or it's fine with 11.04

Comment: I posted some additional help, Take a look at my answer dated 1/31/13. Let me know how it goes